# Discord.js How to make temp channel if the user have null role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This the code, i want to make Temp Channel if the user doesn't have any role on `Let Role =`
awdawdwadwadwadwadwadwadwadwadwadawdwadawdwadwadwadwadwadwadwadwadwa

```
music.on('voiceStateUpdate',(lama, baru) => {
var state = null;  
let Role = baru.roles.find((r) => ["IRON", "BRONZE","SILVER","GOLD","PLATINUM","DIAMOND","IMMORTAL","RADIANT"].includes(r.name));
let gakada = null
  const kategorikanal = '700743802574602260'
  const channelid = '700743824346972231'
  if(!lama.voiceChannel && !baru.voiceChannel) return;
  if(!lama.voiceChannel && baru.voiceChannel) {state = "join"}
  else if(lama.voiceChannel && !baru.voiceChannel) {state = "leave"}
  else if(lama.voiceChannel.id !== baru.voiceChannel.id) {state = "move"}
  else if(lama.voiceChannel.id == baru.voiceChannel.id) return;
  console.log(state);
//!baru.member.roles.has(allowedRole)
  //if(Role === null) return; console.log("ada masalah ni ga punya role orangnya")
if(Role === null) return; console.log("ada masalah ni ga punya role orangnya")
  if(baru.voiceChannelID === channelid && baru.roles.has !== Role) {
     // console.log(Role)
      //console.log(Role.name)
   // const Role = baru.guild.roles.get("724997095236304987");
    baru.guild
    .createChannel(`${Role.name} | ${baru.user.username}`,"voice")
    .then(tempChannel => {
        tempChannel.overwritePermissions(baru.guild.defaultRole.id, {
   CONNECT: false,
})

    tempChannel.overwritePermissions(Role.id, {
        CONNECT: true
    })
      tempChannel.setParent(kategorikanal);
      baru.setVoiceChannel(tempChannel.id);
      tempChannel.setUserLimit("5");
      })

  .catch(console.error)
      
} 
  if(lama.voiceChannelID) {     
      console.log(lama.displayName + ' gabisabgo hrus ada rank ranked ');
    let Role = baru.roles.find((r) => ["IRON", "BRONZE","SILVER","GOLD","PLATINUM","DIAMOND","IMMORTAL","RADIANT"].includes(r.name));

      const voicelama = lama.guild.channels.get(lama.voiceChannelID);

      if(voicelama.name.startsWith(`${Role.name} | ${baru.user.username}`)){
      let sawadikap = `**${baru.user.username}'s**` + " **Team**"
      var koko = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor("#FF4654")
      .setThumbnail(`${baru.user.avatarURL}`)
      .addField('**Good Game Well Played**',`${sawadikap}`)
      .setFooter("@Valorant Indonesia Community." , 'https://i.imgur.com/yPWqxxu.png') 
       voicelama.delete()
      .then(function() {
        music.channels.get('725080861392896101').send(koko)
  })
      .catch(console.error);
  }
    }
         })
```

This project for my private server, please help me to solve this problem. Thanks if u can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the person don't have any role it will set the name to "No roles"

```
Role ? Role.name : "No roles"
```

And the id of the role you want to give the permissions you can change to the user

```
tempChannel.overwritePermissions(Role ? Role.id : baru.id,{ ...
```

Comment: where i must put that

Comment: here `.createChannel(`${Role ? Role.name : "No roles"} | ${baru.user.username}`,"voice")` and `tempChannel.overwritePermissions(Role ? Role.id : baru.id", {`

Comment: what should happen ? you got that return `if(Role === null) return; console.log("ada masalah ni ga punya role orangnya")` ? if yes just comment that code

Comment: its must be create a channel, but still same problem if the user not have the role doesn't create the channel

Comment: comment that line and try again

Comment: where i must put the comment? and comment like what

Comment: `//if(Role === null) return; console.log("ada masalah ni ga punya role orangnya")`

Comment: then how to let people in to channel?

Comment: In that part of the code you closing the access to everyone if you want to open it just changet CONNECT to true
`tempChannel.overwritePermissions(baru.guild.defaultRole.id, {
   CONNECT: false,
})`

Comment: can i make some role array permission ? i mean when someone join with role Radiant
and the bot make the channel name RADIANT | Miez , i want the permission have 2 role
RADIANT & IMMORTAL

Comment: Yes but it's not related to that question